# How do entities have changes tracked when EF query returns duplicates?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

If I create an Entity Framework query that has a join in it which causes the entity on the left side of the join to be duplicated, Do the duplicates' changes get tracked separately or do they stay in sync with each other? For example, if there are multiple drivers per car in the following query:

```
var q = from car in dbContext.Cars
        join driver in dbContext.Drivers on car.CarId equals driver.CarId
        select new { Car = car, Driver = driver };
```

What happens when you modify one of the `Car` entities? Do the other `Car` entities get updated too? Is it the same reference? Or are they tracked separately and, if so, what happens if you modify multiple instances of the same car and call `SaveChanges()`? Which changes win?

Comment: Have you tried to see what happens?

Comment: @DavidG, I'd rather get an official answer than try to guess what is happening beneath the covers.

Comment: I understand that, but with only a little work, you could have added that information to the question.

Comment: [Official Answer](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest)

Comment: There is no official answer. Most of the EF behaviors are undocumented and found from blog posts/experimental. So the non official answer is - they will be one and the same reference.

Comment: It's sort of explained here (although for `ObjectContext`): [Identity Resolution, State Management, and Change Tracking](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896269(v=vs.110).aspx)